# Cannot reach constructor string outside constructor C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to reach the constructor string out side the constructor, but still in same class. This is windows form application! You can read on following code errors and what I've tried so far.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        /*
         * Tried make it internal, gives me error:
         * Invalid token ';' in class, sruct or interface member declaration
        */
        internal name; 
        public Form2(string name)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*
             *  I cannot get the name parameter here from constructor error:
             *  The name 'name' does not exist in current context
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `internal name;` isn't a valid field declaration...

Comment: Yeah saw it from below comments, I'm still learning. Now I've learned to specify the type!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your declaration is wrong, you didn't specify the type:

```
private string name;
```

(it doesn't need to be internal if you want to access it from the same class, so I made it private)

And you need to initialize it in the constructor:

```
this.name = name;
```

---

More explanations:

> I cannot get the name parameter here from constructor

That's because the constructor's parameter is only in scope in the constructor; it doesn't exist when you're in another method. That's why you need to copy it to a *field* (aka class variables) to make it available in the whole class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! An extra + for the extra explanation!

Answer (score 4):

You need to set it

*EDIT* To be fair you don't need it to be internal, can be private if this class is only going to access it.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {   
        internal string name; //THIS LINE HERE CHANGED TO SET THE TYPE

        public Form2(string name)
        {
            this.name = name; //NEED THIS LINE TO SET THE VARIABLE
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name); //SHOW THE NAME
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add below lines of code in your constructor and made changes as shown below :-

1) need to specify the data type of "name"

2) You need to initialize the "name" in your constructor.

3) if you want to use it within same class then make it "private" instead of "internal"

so final code would be:

```
private string name; 

public Form2(string name)
{
   this.name = name;
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right, but @Thomas was first. Still voted this up for an correct answer. Thanks also for pointing out it not need to be internal in same class! Gonna need to read more about private, public and internal etc.

Answer (score 0):

Name parameter used in Form2 constructor is local variable .May be used you need to assign this value as below

```
internal name; 
public Form2(string name)
{
   this.name=name;
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: As you can see in above answers this is not correct since `internal name` need to be `internal string name` .. Need to specify the type! thanks for your time tho

Comment: As TorrBallen mentioned, you need to specify a [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx) when declaring a variable.